# Parsing Logic Operators in a String using Elementtree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I have users that are entering an input of a logic operator in XML and ElementTree is not happy about it. For what we are doing, the ability to include logic operators is essential.

```
until="NavQdrCloseTo(DegOfRad(baseleg_out_qdr)-(nav_radius/fabs(nav_radius))*10) && 10 > fabs(GetPosAlt() - WaypointAlt(WP_BASELEG))"
```

When I parse, I get:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed
```

and it points to the && operator. Is there a way to make ElementTree read logic operators? (Or at least stop throwing this error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` character is special in XML. It cannot appear in its literal form (unescaped) in element content or attribute values. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax for the details.

Your `&&` operator needs to be written as `&amp;&amp;` in order to be accepted by an XML parser.